# Android - RecyclerView item duplication on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am testing a RecyclerView and would like to display a list of Strings. However I keep running into a strange problem. When I scroll my recycler items duplicate.
Here is an image of my issue:
[image]
Here is my adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LessonAdapter.TopicViewHolder> {


Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> mData;

LessonAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> list) {
    this.mContext = context;
    initData();
}

public class TopicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mTopicIndexText;
    TextView mTopicNameText;

    public TopicViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTopicIndexText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.index);
        mTopicNameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.topic);
    }
}

private void initData(){

    mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    mData.add("Africa");
    mData.add("Antartica");
    mData.add("Asia");
    mData.add("Australia");
    mData.add("Europe");
    mData.add("North America");
    mData.add("South America");
    mData.add("Africa");
    mData.add("Antartica");
    mData.add("Asia");
    mData.add("Australia");
    mData.add("Europe");
    mData.add("North America");
    mData.add("South America");
    mData.add("Africa");
    mData.add("Antartica");
    mData.add("Asia");
    mData.add("Australia");
    mData.add("Europe");
    mData.add("North America");
    mData.add("South America");
}


@Override
public TopicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lesson_item, parent, false);
    TopicViewHolder viewHolder = new TopicViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TopicViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTopicNameText.setText(mData.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
```

}

And the layout of each RecyclerItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/index"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1.0"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:textColor="#393C3D"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/index"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#393C3D"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And how I initialize my RecyclerView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lesson, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lesson_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
```

And the layout of the RecyclerView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lesson_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't you also want to set the text for mTopicIndexText in your ViewHolder when onBindViewHolder is called?

Comment: Try sending array from activity  rather than blank adapter

Comment: @Michael Krause Not at the moment. But that shouldn't matter anyway should it ?

Comment: No - it shouldn't.  Does the RecyclerView render the items properly when first displayed or does it have this doubling effect even without scrolling?

Comment: It renders fine when first displayed.

Comment: It seems to me that the Activity creates twice fragment. Check it.

Comment: @KosWarm can you please add your comment as an answer. THANK YOU SO MUCH ! I was actually adding the Fragment twice once in onCreate and then another time on a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Activity creates the fragment twice